# how we can display unique names form array List into vf page

Tags: visualforce

How i can write logic in vf page to display unique name which is stored in list.
Example: Vf page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Alldata}" var="data2">                                       
        <apex:outputText style="font-size:16px;color:#246487;clear:both;font-weight:normal;padding:5px 0 0px 2px;" 
                         value=" {!data2.name__c}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

My controller is :

```
public List<Name__c> getAlldata()
{
// my code
}

suppose my controller send : jone , joy , amol, jone. 
In vf page i want to display only: jone , joy , amol.
```

I have to write logic in vf page i can't send unique names from controller.so please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Better to use a map or a set of Name__c then.

Comment: no i can't change controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set` instead of `List` on page as:

```
  public List<Name__c> getAlldata()
    {
    // my code
    }

    // Sets are unique. You need to create get set for it
    Set<Name__c> nameSet = new Set<Name__c>(getAlldata());
```

On VF page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!nameSet}" var="data2">                                       
        <apex:outputText style="font-size:16px;color:#246487;clear:both;font-weight:normal;padding:5px 0 0px 2px;" 
                         value=" {!data2.name__c}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

update:

```
public Set<Name__c> getAlldata()
{
  // my code
  return new Set<Name__c>(listGeneratedFromAboveCode);
}
```

Comment: I know set will give me unique name but i can't change anything from controller side. Here i have give simple controller method but in actually it is more complected so i can't do anything in controller side i have to use something in vf page only.

Comment: You need to change a single line in  `public List<Name__c> getAlldata()
    {
    // my code
    }` @JayantJadhav

Comment: No actually my method looks like public List<List<List<Name__c>>> getAlldata() and i am not just sending names but also some other data like each person info.

Comment: It is also possible:  `Set<List<Set<Name__c>>>` any combination as per need. You should use `Map` or wrapper class instead of, to simplify your code. @JayantJadhav

Comment: This is fine but a am loosing some info. And if u use Set u can't predict order of displaying stored element.

Comment: @JayantJadhav Therefore I recommend `maps`

Comment: i can't change controller so if u have any other suggestions to do this in vf then please share.